# adding dynamic markers with google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have line chart I have created with Google charts.  I'd like to add a dynamic marker to mark a particular point on that chart (and later I'll want to add a horizontal line).  This looks like it should be possible using the chm parameter, but I can't get it to work-- the chart draws, but no marker.

I've tried various permutations with the chm parameter to no avail.  It looks like it should be a valid parameter for a line chart.  What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
    function drawIterationHistory() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Iteration');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Other');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Fail');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Not Run');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Pass');
        data.addRows([
          ['1', 0, 5, 90, 5],
          ['2', 1, 8, 82, 10],
          ['3', 2, 12, 60, 40],
          ['4', 2, 30, 20, 60],
          ['5', null, null, null, null],
          ['6', null, null, null, null]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 450, height: 240,
          title: 'Test Plan Iteration History',
          isStacked: 'true',
          hAxis: {title: 'Iteration'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Test Cases'},
          chm: '@a,FF0000,1,2:20,1' // This line does not seem to have an effect
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('iterationHistory'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: `chm` option is part of Google Image Charts which was depreciated in April 2012. How it was used is described in this nice tutorial [How to use Google Charts API with 6 examples](http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/).